# GitAhead: Asking for credentials when trying to push - not able to continue

Tags: gitlab, gitahead

I'm trying to push to a GitLab repository. I'm already logged in/authenticated and I'm able to fetch all my GitLab projects.

The repository was imported to GitLab from GitHub.

I was also able to push normally with a different repository, but with this one I get a "HTTPS Credentials" dialog asking for a username and password. Supplying my GitLab username and a personal access token does not work.

I'm running GitAhead 2.5.11 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote was still set to the GitHub URL instead of the GitLab URL, so I was actually trying to push to GitHub with my GitLab credentials.

Setting the remote to the correct GitLab URL did the trick.